# Specifying glob patterns as Makefile targets

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

My `make` version on macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.6 looks like this:

```
$ make --version
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
```

My current directory looks like this:

```
$ ls -1
Makefile
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
```

My `Makefile` looks like this:

```
*.txt: FORCE
        echo Target $@ invoked

FORCE:
```

I am able to use this `Makefile` like this:

```
$ make a.txt
echo Target a.txt invoked
Target a.txt invoked
$ make b.txt
echo Target b.txt invoked
Target b.txt invoked
$ make c.txt
echo Target c.txt invoked
Target c.txt invoked
```

Where is this behavior of `*.txt` expanding to matching targets in the current directory documented? I tried searching the man pages and documents but could not find anything that specifies that we can use glob patterns as target. Can I rely on this behavior in my `Makefile`s?

Comment: Correct syntax is `%.txt`. `*.txt` could be an obscure anachronism.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output from `make --version` .

Comment: @G.M. I have added it now. It is `GNU Make 3.81` on macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.6.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Rule-Syntax.html) right in the introduction to rule syntax:

> The targets are file names, separated by spaces. Wildcard characters may be used (see Using Wildcard Characters in File Names)

and the entire section [Using Wildcard Characters in File Names](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcards.html).

You cannot just look at man pages: the man pages only describe the command line interface and possible the barest summary of makefile syntax.  They don't attempt to describe everything about how to write a makefile.

If you looked in the GNU make manual but didn't find this I'd be interested to understand what you searched for and where you expected to find the information so we can think about improving the docs.